# Laravel query result, change the column name into numeric

Tags: laravel

I just wonder how to convert the key of query result into numeric. This is my query result for the example:

```
$result = [{
   "lat": "43289043208",
   "lng": "-3890423802"
},...]
```

What I want is

```
$result = [{
   0: "43289043208",
   1: "-3890423802"
},...]
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use this, and it solved for now

```
$table_data = DB::table($table)->select(DB::raw("$lat_field as '0'"), DB::raw("$lng_field as '1'"))->get();
```

Comment: You should also indicate this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_values() method.

And iterate the result array

```
$newArray = [];
foreach(json_decode($result) as $res)
{
 $newArray[] = array_values($res);
}
```

Comment: Found this error: 
array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

I have already add ->toArray() at the last code of my database query.

Comment: @PirmanDwiana i updated my answer json_decode your result to array